# How to import sql file of size more than 500MB to cpanel phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have .sql file of 550MB, tried to import with phpmyadmin in cpanel. It gives an error of max file size.
Can anyone give me idea for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to do via command line? If so, upload file to server and do something like : $ mysql -u db_username -p dbname < import.sql

Comment: The worst case if you cannot do via command line, just split the file into smaller parts, and do one by one.

Comment: if you are having to deal with 500Mb data dumps a company that only offers cpanel is very bad choice.

Comment: Thanks, @SIDU. But I am not able to do with the command line. Finally, I did by splitting into smaller parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a Remote `SQL` connection with the server,

   it can be via:

   [image: Remote MySql]

   Or via `SSH` account.
2. Open that connection from a client app like `MySqlWorkbench` or from terminal.
3. Run the script file directly, rather than open it.